Issues Setting Up ShadCN with Next.js: Bun Cache Errors and Installation Failures
Issues Setting Up ShadCN with Next.js: Bun Cache Errors and Installation Failures
Hello, Developer Community!
I'm trying to set up ShadCN in my Next.js project, but I’ve been running into persistent issues related to Bun, dependency installation, and cache errors. I've tried multiple approaches, but nothing seems to work, and I’m hoping someone here can help!

I’d really appreciate any suggestions or guidance! If you’ve faced similar issues, please let me know how you resolved them.
Thank you in advance! 
What I'm Trying to Do:

Initialize ShadCN in a Next.js project using:
npx shadcn init  

Install necessary dependencies:
bun add tailwindcss-animate class-variance-authority lucide-react clsx tailwind-merge

Configure Tailwind CSS and import aliases as part of the ShadCN setup.



The Errors I'm Facing:
1. Bun Installation Fails with Cache Errors:
When Bun is used to install dependencies during shadcn init, I get errors like this:
error: moving "@ts-morph/common" to cache dir failed EPERM: Operation not permitted (NtSetInformationFile()) From: .df1fffffef2fbaae-00000007.common To: @ts-morph/common@0.19.0@@@1 error: InstallFailed extracting tarball from @ts-morph/common error: Failed to link shadcn: EBUSY
2. Force ShadCN to Use npm Fails:
When I try to force ShadCN to use npm:
npx shadcn init --package-manager npm
I get this error:
error: could not find bin metadata file Bun failed to remap this bin to its proper location within node_modules. Please run 'bun install --force' in the project root and try it again.
3. Manual Dependency Installation and Retry:
After manually installing the dependencies using npm:
npm install tailwindcss-animate class-variance-authority lucide-react clsx tailwind-merge
And retrying npx shadcn init, the same Bun-related cache issues persist.

What I’ve Tried So Far:

Cleared Bun Cache: Deleted the Bun cache directory from C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\bun.
Ran Commands as Administrator: Tried all commands in Administrator mode.
Removed and Reinstalled Bun: Uninstalled and reinstalled Bun to ensure no corruption.
Switched to npm: Tried using npm for everything, but shadcn init still defaults to Bun.
Manually Configured Tailwind and Dependencies: Manually installed the required packages and updated the Tailwind configuration.


My Environment:

OS: Windows 11
Node.js Version: 20.15.1
Bun Version: 1.1.20
Next.js Version: 14.2.14
ShadCN Version: 2.1.0


What I Need Help With:

How can I prevent Bun from interfering with the setup entirely? Is there a way to globally disable Bun for this project?
Has anyone successfully used ShadCN with npm on Windows? If so, are there any specific configurations or steps required?
Is there a manual way to set up ShadCN without relying on the shadcn init command?

I’d really appreciate any suggestions or guidance! If you’ve faced similar issues, please let me know how you resolved them.

Try installing with this command bunx --bun shadcn@latest init given in the docs

Hi Govind,
Thanks for the suggestion!
I tried bunx --bun shadcn@latest init, but the same issue persists:
error: moving "@ts-morph/common" to cache dir failed EPERM: Operation not permitted (NtSetInformationFile()) From: .5d52cbcf61df4f70-00000001.common To: @ts-morph/common@0.19.0@@@1 error: InstallFailed extracting tarball from @ts-morph/common
I’ve tried running as admin and clearing the cache, but no luck. Any other workarounds?
Thanks for your help!
